# Error in a ManyToMany Relationship on Hibernate-JPA

Tags: eclipse, jpa, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

I have a large DB on MySql Workbench and I'm trying to map the relationship between the entities on Eclipse Mars thanks to Hibernate and the JPA module. The fact is that I receive the error:
"In attribute 'personAddresses', the "mapped by" attribute 'peopleAdd' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship."
This are the entities involved.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0nz4.png)

I've to say that making a forward engineering, Hibernate creating for me an AddressId class, where the composite primary key of Address is mapped. I suspect that the problem could be this, but I'm not certain, can you help me please?
Under I post the code so that it's more clear to understand how the classes are implemented.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AddressId.class)
@Table(schema = "YouDroop", name = "Address")
public class Address implements Serializable
{
...

private Collection<Person> peopleAdd = new HashSet<Person>();

@Id
@Column(name = "Address", length = 45, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String address;
@Id
@Column(name = "Number", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int number;

...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
           name = "PersonHasAddress",
           joinColumns = {
                           @JoinColumn(name = "Address_Address", referencedColumnName = "Address", nullable = false),
                           @JoinColumn(name = "Address_Number", referencedColumnName = "Number", nullable = false)
                           },
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Person_Email", referencedColumnName = "Email", nullable = false)}
           )
public Collection<Person> getPeopleAddressed(){
    return this.peopleAdd;
}

public void setPeopleAddressed(Collection<Person> people){
    this.peopleAdd = people;
}
}

public class AddressId implements Serializable
{

private String address;
private int number;

public AddressId(){}

public AddressId(String address, int number) {
    super();
    this.address = address;
    this.number = number;
}

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person", schema = "YouDroop", uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NickName"),
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "Password") })
public class Person implements Serializable
{
...

private Collection<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "peopleAdd")
public Collection<Address> getPersonAddresses(){
    return this.addresses;
}

public void setPersonAddresses(Collection<Address> addresses){
    this.addresses = addresses;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you placed you @ManyToMany annotation on your getter method (or property) and not on the field. The mappedBy attribute should reference the property instead and not the field.

```
@ManyToMany
public Collection<Person> getPeopleAddressed() {
...
}
```

So your mappedBy attribute should have been

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="peopleAddressed")
public Collection<Address> getPersonAddresses() {
...
}
```

Comment: So if i want to map the field, I've to put the annotation on the field, while if I want to map the method, I've to put the annotation on the method (like I've done)? Is it correct?